# Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I've been spending like a whole day just to figure out what is wrong with my coding. Can someone tell me what should i alter just to make my coding working. Thanksssss :)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ExpTab (username,month,ex1,p1,ex2,p2,ex3,p3,ex4,p4,ex5,p5,ex6,p6,ex7,p7,ex8,p8,,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8) Values (@name,@month1,@ex1s,@p1s,@ex2s,@p2s,@ex3s,@p3s,@ex4s,@p4s,@ex5s,@p5s,@ex6s,@p6s,@ex7s,@p7s,@ex8s,@p8s)", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Membership.GetUser().UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month1", Label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex1s", Label18.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1s", Label20.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex2s", Label2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2s", Label21.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex3s", Label3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3s", Label22.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex4s", Label4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4s", Label23.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex5s", Label5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5s", Label24.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex6s", Label6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6s", Label25.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex7s", Label7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7s", Label26.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex8s", Label8.Text);     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8s", Label27.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I really need help :(

Comment: you hava a double "," in the SQL column names, p8,,p3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is this little snippet:

```
... p7,ex8,p8,,p3,p4,p5 ...
             ^^
```

meant to be?

That's a rhetorical question by the way, since at least one commenter didn't understand that :-) That's where your trouble lies.

In fact, since you have 24 column names (excluding the empty one between the commas) and only 18 values to be inserted (and also based on the column/value names), it's a near-certainty that the entire section from that second comma onwards is superfluous. Try removing the entire `,,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8` and using this:

```
insert into ExpTab ( 
    username, month, ex1, p1, ex2, p2, ex3, p3,
    ex4, p4, ex5, p5, ex6, p6, ex7, p7, ex8, p8
) values (
    @name, @month1, @ex1s, @p1s, @ex2s, @p2s, @ex3s, @p3s,
    @ex4s, @p4s, @ex5s, @p5s, @ex6s, @p6s, @ex7s, @p7s, @ex8s, @p8s)
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I think it is meant to have only 1 comma. Why are you asking a question as an answer? If you need help you should create your own question, or at least make this a comment to the original post

Comment: @musefan, the question is rhetorical. I _know_ what the problem is :-) OP has cut-and-pasted in some superfluous column names, not just one comma. That's evident from the mismatch between column names and values.

Comment: Thank you everyone. U guys really helped me. Thanks a lot. This really make my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 commas in your INSERT statement next to each other:

```
ex8,p8,,p3,p4
```

Remove one of these commas, and that should solve your error.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma in your code around "p8,,p3" -- remove that. Also, it would be helpful if you posted the full error message next time instead of relying on our psychic debugging skills :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two commas in your column definition: `..p8,,p3..`

Answer (score 1):

I have done the modification on your statement, use the below one it will work

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ExpTab (username,month,ex1,p1,ex2,p2,ex3,p3,ex4,p4,ex5,p5,ex6,p6,ex7,p7,ex8,p8,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8) Values (@name,@month1,@ex1s,@p1s,@ex2s,@p2s,@ex3s,@p3s,@ex4s,@p4s,@ex5s,@p5s,@ex6s,@p6s,@ex7s,@p7s,@ex8s,@p8s)", conn);
```

Comment: @user1220691, I'm not sure entirely _why_ this is the accepted answer, it still has the incompatibility between columns and arguments. See my answer below for the full details, or feel free to copy that info into here. I dislike answers that still have problems but, since it's accepted, there's naught I can do about that, so would prefer the information to be copied in.

Comment: yeah. Wrongly selected. Sorry n thanks. Have a nice day paxdiablo :)

Answer (score 1):

In your sql you have this

```
ex8,p8,,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8)
```

between p8 and p3 you have `,,` that should either be a single `,` or should have a parameter in it.

Comment: This is really what im looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

check your query you have the place with ,,

Also make sure you escape your input data, cause your query is easy for SQL-injection